# v-toolbar not behaving responsively

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am trying to implement vuetify in my project. I am newbie in VueJs & vuetify too.

I am trying to use a toolbar which contains a rounded image on the  right corner. But, It is not responsive. When i open developer option and decrease the screen size to that of mobile. The rounded image does not render.

I tried using plain tags but it is actually disrupting the layout.

Here is the code
VuetifyTest.vue:

```
<template lang="html">
    <v-toolbar>
        <v-toolbar-side-icon>
            <!-- <v-img src="../assets/mad_logo.png" aspect-ratio="1.7"></v-img> -->
        </v-toolbar-side-icon>
        <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">       
        <v-layout
            align-center
            justify-space-around
            wrap
        >
            <v-avatar
            :tile= false 
            size="36"
            color="grey lighten-4"
            >
            <img src="../assets/static.jpeg" alt="avatar">
            </v-avatar>
        </v-layout>
        </v-toolbar-items>
    </v-toolbar>


</template>

<script lang="js">
  export default  {
    name: 'VuetifyTest',
    props: [],
    mounted() {

    },
    data() {
      return {

      }
    },
    methods: {

    },
    computed: {

    }
}
</script>

<style scoped >

</style>
```

This is how it looks like in laptop screen

[image]

This is how it looks like in mobile screen

[image]

How do i change the code to make it responsive

PS: I also tried reducing the screen size while viewing [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/toolbars) in reduced screen size. 
Even though it showed like this..
[image]

Even though the official documentation have this problem?
How do i make it responsive..

thanks!

Comment: Did you try the `app` option ? (This will only work if your toolabr is outside of the `v-content`).

Comment: I dont have any idea what you are trying to say :P...I am a newbie here

Comment: `<v-toolbar app fixed>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to specify `v-layout` within the `v-toolbar` - if you remove the `v-layout` and replace it with just the `v-avatar`, it works.. Examples are below:

[[CodePen Mirror]](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/ewJOJY)

***Snippet:***

```js
new Vue({ el: "#app" })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-toolbar>
      <v-toolbar-side-icon>
      </v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-avatar :tile=false size="36" color="grey lighten-4">
        <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?img=3" alt="avatar">
      </v-avatar>
    </v-toolbar>
  </v-app>
</div>
```